# AWS CLI - JMESPath query to find vpc-id by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to list the VPC id's which have a particular tag (Name=MyVPC).

I am aware that I can use `--filter` and run:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=MyVPC --query 'Vpcs[].VpcId'
```

This works completely fine.

Is there a way I can achieve this without using `--filter` and only use JMESPath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --query 'Vpcs[?Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[?Value==`MyVPC`]].VpcId' --output text
```

Comment: To my knowledge, you can avoid using JMESPATH here and just rely on the `--filters` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --query 'Vpcs[?contains(Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[], `MyVPC`) == `true`].[VpcId]' --output text
```